# Proving a summation result using strong induction

Tags: summation, induction

I was recently taught strong induction in class and overall I'm still learning the topic. I am currently stuck on a problem and I don't even know where to begin with it. A starting place or hint would be great.

[image: Image of Problem]

Comment: "Hint : use a technique of exercise 3" ... So we need to have a look at exercise 3 ... This apart, it looks like a "telescopic summation" : try to factorize $j(j+1)(j+2)-(j+1)(j+2)(j+3)$ as a starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $k$ and apply induction on $n$. So, let us assume that $$\sum_{j=1}^\color{blue}nj(j+1)(j+2)\dots(j+k-1)=\frac{\color{blue}n(\color{blue}n+1)(\color{blue}n+2)\dots(\color{blue}n+k)}{k+1}.$$ Then
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{j=1}^{\color{red}{n+1}}j(j+1)(j+2)\dots(j+k-1)\\
&=[(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\dots(n+1+k-1)]+\sum_{j=1}^nj(j+1)(j+2)\dots(j+k-1)\\
&=[(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\dots(n+k)]+\sum_{j=1}^nj(j+1)(j+2)\dots(j+k-1)\\
&=\overbrace{[(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\dots(n+k)]}+\frac{n\overbrace{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\dots(n+k)}}{k+1}\\
&=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\dots(n+k)\cdot \left[1+\frac{n}{k+1}\right]\\
&=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\dots(n+k)\cdot \left[\frac{k+1+n}{k+1}\right]\\
&=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\dots(n+k)\cdot \left[\frac{n+k+1}{k+1}\right]\\
&=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\dots(n+k)(n+k+1)}{k+1}\\
&=\frac{\color{red}{(n+1)}\cdot[\color{red}{(n+1)}+1)]\cdot[\color{red}{(n+1)}+2]\dots[\color{red}{(n+1)}+k]}{k+1}
\end{align}$$
Hope this help.

Comment: Nicely avoids the usual magic telescoping sum.

Comment: @marty cohen I did it correctly?

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: Where did the [1+(n)/(k+1)] come from in the 5th line?

Comment: @Anthony L The common factor is the one that I marked as braces. Factor out it to obtain line 5.